# Iterate over values in a table only if they are in a region

Tags: differential-equations, export, list-manipulation, regions

I made some pretty simple PDE's in non-square regions, and I am attempting to output the data (t, x, y, funcval) out to a .csv file (I know, terrible format for this, but it was a requirement for the project...).

Currently I have solved the PDE with

```
MatRegion = RegularPolygon[3, 7];
heateq = 
 {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] ==       
   0.01 (Derivative[0, 2, 0][u][t, x, y] +
         Derivative[0, 0, 2][u][t, x, y])  , 
   u[0, x, y] == 20* E^(-5 ((x)^2 + (y^2)))*Sin[x]^2, 
   DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, True]}
heatsol =  NDSolveValue[heateq, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, y} \[Element] MatRegion]
```

This then gives the interpolating polynomial heatsol[t, x, y].
Then I wish to output the grid at each time step, so I have the code

```
Data2 = Partition[Flatten[Table[{t, x, y,  heatsol[t, x, y]}, 
{t, 0, 10, 0.1}, {x, -2.9, 2.9, 0.1}, {y, -2.7, 3, 0.1}]], 4];
StringData2 = ExportString[Data2, "CSV"];
Export["Data2.csv", StringData2]
```

Which is great, BUT the interpolating polynomial isn't completely defined on the range

```
{x, -2.9, 2.9}, {y, -2.7, 3}
```

but rather only on MatRegion.
Is there a way that I can only get the x,y values when they are both in the specified region? I can imagine I would have to probably write my own implementation of Table[...] that uses If[] statements to ensure they are in the region, but if there is a clever way that would be ideal.

Comment: The actual data you want is `heatsol["ElementMesh"]["Coordinates"]`, `heatsol["Coordinates"][[1]]` (times), and `heatsol["ValuesOnGrid"]`, perhaps.  Check out their `Dimensions[]`.  You seem to have values at 979 points at 41 different times.